# How to make a framework-agnostic composer package that uses session?

Tags: php, frameworks, composer-php, decoupling

I'm refectoring my existing CodeIgniter library in to a reusable and framework-agnostic composer package.

My Code depends on CI's `session` and `uri` libraries, and views.

I watched [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV4iPSHbonk).
Read [this](http://adamwathan.me/2014/01/05/decoupling-your-packages-from-your-framework)

Here's what I've thought to do:

- create a session interface
- create a class which uses CI's session by extending the interface

but I'm still kinda unclear on how to do it.

### Update

I almost nailed it.the same thing is implemented [here](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/tree/master/src/Cartalyst/Sentry) as discussed in the talk  linked above.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you have an array called `$_SESSION`. You could implement a `class`, called `SessionHandler`. In that `class` you should create a method to start the session and another to destroy the session. You can also create methods to do other things as well. A very basic implementation would be like this:

```
class SessionHandler {

    private static $isStarted = false;

    public static function startSession() {
        if (!SessionHandler::$isStarted && session_status() === 1) {
            SessionHandler::$isStarted = true;
            session_start();
        }
    }

    public function destroySession() {
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function getElement($key, $defaultValue = null) {
        return ((isset($_SESSION[$key])) ? ($_SESSION[$key]) : ($defaultValue));
    }

    public function setElement($key, $value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        SessionHandler::startSession();
    }

}
```

Comment: I agree with Lajos Arpad here. You can also checkout an example how it is done in Aura.Auth https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Auth/blob/d6ba1f8bc7762f62cc5ac14b375d69667bf2c424/src/Session/Session.php and https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Auth/blob/075e22ca8a155e8f01283f8f0740b17c052f45f3/src/Session/Segment.php . It don't start session first but only when you call start though.